# Django: custom validation message

Tags: django, forms, validation

I'm having a problem with changing my validation message from
'Please fill out this field' to 'Custom message blablabla':
I tried to use something like this:

```
class NameForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super(NameForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          self.fields['name'].error_messages['required'] = 'Testing'

    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ['name']
        widgets = {'name': forms.TextInput(
                     attrs={'id': 'player_name', 'required': True, 'placeholder': 'Player name...','value':'player1','title':'write here your name'}
            )
        }
```

but it doesn't seem to work. What am I missing? How can I customize my error message for a specific field when required is raised?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384891/django-models-forms-replace-this-field-is-required-message

Comment: @Jingo I saw that. I believe that issue can be similar but not duplicated. I am not quite sure if an error message is the same of validation message.  'Please fill out this field' is a error or validation message? if it is error message what am i doing wrong? if is a validation message how can i do this? Thanks by the way

Comment: Your example code **does work** for me (after I made a couple of minor changes). That means your problem is probably somewhere in your actual code, which you haven't shown us.

Comment: @Alasdair, thanks for your opinion. Please checkout my question again with my own code.

Comment: Your updated example code still works for me in Django 1.7.X. What do your view and template look like?

Comment: That's a HTML5 validation check. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33014889/how-to-remove-please-fill-out-this-field-pop-up-when-click-on-submit-form-in-a).
And [this for custom example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753881/changing-the-language-of-error-message-in-required-field-in-html5-contact-form).