# how to remove "please fill out this field" pop up when click on submit form in angularjs but other validations should work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, validation

I want to remove the "please fill out this field" pop-up as validation and normal validations which are declared should display.

Html:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <form role="form" id="createForm" v name="createForm"  ng-submit="createAdminGroup(adminGroupData)">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : createForm.firstName.$invalid && !createForm.firstName.$pristine}">
            <label class="label1">First Name</label>
            <input name="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName"  type="text" ng-model="adminGroupData.firstName  " required/>
         <span style="color:red" ng-show="createForm.firstName.$invalid  && !createForm.firstName.$pristine">Please enter first name</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="label1">Last Name </label>
            <input name="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastNmae"  type="text" ng-model="adminGroupData.lastName" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="label1"> Email Id </label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control"  placeholder="email@xyz.com" value=""ng-model="adminGroupData.email"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="label1"> Password </label>
            <input name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password"  value=""  ng-model="adminGroupData.password" />
        </div>

        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Save</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="cancel" type="button" onclick='handleCancelCreateAdmin()'> Back </button>

        </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please take the time to look at the formatting in the preview of your question before hitting the post button, that makes it a lot easier to help you

Comment: add `novalidate` to `form`

Answer (score 25):

Add `novalidate` attribute to your `form` to disable **browser default validation**

**For Ex**

```
<form role="form" novalidate id="createForm" v name="createForm"  ng-submit="createAdminGroup(adminGroupData)">
```

**[`Find more here`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)**

Answer (score 8):

Add the attribute **formnovalidate** inside your submit button:

Example:

```
<button name="submit" type="submit" formnovalidate class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
```

This will disable only the browser form validation. You still have the validation from your AngularJS code.

You can see the W3C specification [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-formnovalidate)

I had the same problem a few days ago and that's how I managed to solve

Answer (score 3):

I just tried this and it worked:

> oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(' ')"  oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" >

I have add a space between the two single quotes.

Since i added a bootstrap tooltip on my input fields and required, the invalid input comes to focus and displays the tooltip value.

It was simpler than I thought it would be.

Answer (score 2):

### title=""

---

The tooltip appears even when input is outside of form and for those cases it does not work the `novalidate`.

One solution is to remove `required`, but if you have a large codebase then a quick hack will be to add `title=""`.

`<input type="text" required title="" />`